# How to exclude the codes that are "grey" in the vscode editor from the global search result?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After installing the c/c++ IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code and configure the c_cpp_properties.json, the code that is disabled by MACRO is in grey colour that indicates not valid codes.

For example, the `printf()` statement in the following code is grey.

```
void Test(void)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    printf("release mode.");
#endif
}
```

My question is is it possible to exclude this line from the global search result in vscode?
I don't want to exclude the complete file but only some lines in the file.

Here is an explanation of why I want this feature.

In our code, the test code is written in the same file together with the application code. The test code is placed between #ifdef UNIT_TEST and #endif, so it is easy to disable/enable the test code by turn on/off the MARCO UNIT_TEST in the IDE configurations.
However, you know the test code created many test cases to call a function to be tested many times, so it is very confusing when I trying to search where a function is called in the project. So many places to call this function while most are in the test code!

Comment: You can't, search feature just scans all documents as pure text and it is oblivious of language features like macros, preprocessor and so on. Maybe some plugin is extending search functionality but I doubt it. Anyway it would be better if you explain why you need this since it is possible there is an alternative approach to your problem. For example some IDE can index not only all symbols definitions, but also all places where they are actually used (VS + ReSharper can).

Comment: *"indicates not valid codes"* s/valid/active/.

Comment: This is pure VS question. C++ tag seems to be not relevant.

Comment: Then why search commented code? In practice most of the time you want to find all results. For example, if you want to replace `printf` with `myprintf`, you need to replace then inside #ifdef/#endif. Some might compile outside of the IDE and define might not be properly set. In the end better to search everything. Also #ifdef should not be used so much that it would really have such an impact on results.

Comment: @MarekR, I need this just for convenience. In our code, the test code is written in the same file together with the application code. The test code is placed between #ifdef UNIT_TEST and #endif, so it is easy to disable the test code by disabling the MARCO UNIT_TEST.

Comment: @Phil1970, you are right. We turn on/off the MARCO in the IAR IDE to select application code or test code. The unit test code is in the same file as the application code and is included by the #ifdef. In this case, if I want to know where a function is called, I want to exclude the place that is in the unit test cases.